# Benford's law is not working?

Tags: graphs, randomness

So I recently came across Benford's law and immediately tried to code it out but the answer I got was rather confusing. I've been thinking about it for about an hour now and still can't get it,  I think my code is correct I'm pretty sure it is but the result is just not the one others get. Here's the code:

```
float[] a=new float[10000],flag=new float[10];

for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
  {
    a[i]=floor(random(0,99999));
      if(a[i]>10000)
         a[i]=floor(a[i]/10000);   
      if(a[i]>1000)
         a[i]=floor(a[i]/1000);
      if(a[i]>100)
         a[i]=floor(a[i]/100);
      if(a[i]>10)
         a[i]=floor(a[i]/10);
    
      for(int k=1;k<10;k++)
       {
          if(a[i]==k)
            flag[k]++;
       }

  }
```

Though I get roughly the same *flag[k]* (around 1100) but according to Benford's law that should not be the case. Can someone help me tell how my code is wrong?

Comment: The typical explanation is that Benford's law applies to quantities whose fluctuations are proportional to their size. This means they grow exponentially, or follow a log-normal distribution (many naturally occurring quantities do). Your code is (I believe) sampling a uniform distribution, though, which wouldn't follow Benford's law.

Comment: @DanDoel I don't think so, the problem was that I had a specific cutoff I made the cutoff and it magically appears again.

Comment: I made the cutoff random*

Comment: Some tips regarding your code: (1) `a` should be of integer type (2) there is absolutely no need to store the entire array `a`; it suffices to store only a single entry (3) you can replace the `if`s with a simple loop: `while (a >= 10) a /= 10` (4) you can replace the final loop with a single statement `flag[a[i]]++`.

Comment: This is really a math question, better asked at [math.se].

Comment: @Yuval filmus thanks for the optimizations! I just wanted to implement it so didn't think about optimizing but wow that shortened the code insanely!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3904913/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/132164/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

That's because for the numbers from 10,000 to 99,999 the first digit is equally likely, same for numbers from 1,000 to 9,999 etc.

Benford's law depends on random numbers whose logarithm has a linear distribution over a not too small range. Take random numbers x from 0 to 999,999, then calculate 10^(x/200000) and you'll find that Benford's law will hold.

But measure the height of adult people in feet, and 95% start with 5 or 6, a few percent start with 4, and very few with 7 or 3. It's not a law that applies to every set of numbers. (Measure people in meters, and 98% start with 1, a few with 2, and very few start with a 9 or even 8. )

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer, We need to make the maximum possible digit random too. The result keep better-representing benford's law the more and more random variables I use

here's the new code that gave me a very satisfactory result

```
float a,p,q,r;

  for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
  {
    r=random(0,99999);
    q=random(0,r);
    p=random(0,q);
    a=floor(random(0,p));
      while(a>=10)
       a/=10;

      flag[a]++;
  }
```

Result : *flag[1]* = 3050 (expected 3010) .
*flag[2]* = 1746 (expected 1760) and so on(of course they keep changing but do remain within 2-3% of the expected outcome).

Comment: This is effectively no longer sampling a uniform distribution. For instance, the only way to pick p=99999 is to pick r=99999 and q=99999 first, so the overall chance is $10^{-15}$. However, 0 can be picked regardless of the previous two choices, and in fact becomes more likely when smaller numbers are picked for q, which becomes more likely when smaller numbers are picked for r. If you work out the actual distribution you are sampling, I imagine it will be exponentially weighted toward 0.

Comment: Perhaps I should say, it is probably not _actually_ exponentially weighted. But the more intermediate steps added, the closer to exponential weighting it will be.

Comment: @DanDoel I think that is the point of benford's law that in reality since we don't know the upper limit it can be 1000 or 9999 or anything so when you average out you'll get more thing starting with one than with 2 or 3 or 4 etc.